# Can you wipe a ps3 clean to sell but keep the downloaded games on it

Tags: ps3

Can i wipe clean a ps3 for sale while keeping the downloaded games on it? Or will that leave me vulnerable to cc theft or other fraud.

Comment: Welcom to Arqade! This is an excellent question!

Answer (score 3):

You can physically remove the hard drive, I think It's just a single screw.

Make sure to de-activate your Playstation account (or, specifically, the account that **purchased** the games) on the PS3 before you sell it.

https://www.playstation.com/en-ie/get-help/help-library/my-account/device-activation-deactivation/how-to-deactivate-a-playstation-3-system/

You can only activate your account (and ergo play your games) on two PS3 consoles *at the same time*, so if you want to re-download your games onto another PS3 that won't be a problem provided that you haven't activated your account on two other PS3's already.

CC theft probably isn't a threat, but if you're worried here's instructions on how to factory reset your PS3:
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2265/ps3_how_to_factory_hard_reset/

protip: The two activations system can be used by two people to effectively make all PS3 PSN games half-price. "Gamepooling" actually used to support 5 PS3s.

Comment: Being the PS3 HDD formatted with a special version of JFS (with encryption), there is REALLY no way to read the FS after you erase it: every PS3 has got its encryption key, and if you plug the HDD into a SATA-USB adapter to see the sectors, they will be unreadable, encrypted. Since OP has bought digital games with your PSN account, then he/she will have to download them newly on another PS3. As @Lee Gildemeester said, it's fundamental to deactivate the PS3 before even erasing its HDD. If that isn't done, the only way out is going to Sony Account Settings and forcing PS3 deactivation.

Comment: ... Which will rid you of this privilege and arouse suspicion at Sony